# Wordpress site in browser gives a safety warning ' Deceptive site ahead'

Tags: wordpress

On the website https://www.aardappelspeciaal.nl/ we have a 'Deceptive site ahead' warning.

We have contacted our hosting and they say that the SSL certificate is installed wel. They have also checked the site on suspicious activities and reported to us:

> I checked this as an extra service but unfortunately I cannot find out
> whether this website has actually been hacked. I have checked the
> files and currently a recent version of wordpress is running and the
> core files seem fine, see the checks below.
> [aardappel1@. public_html]$ wp core version
> 5.4.2
> [aardappel1@. public_html]$ wp core verify-checksums
> Warning: File should not exist: wp-itapi.php
> Success: WordPress installation verifies against checksums.

They advice us to contact a wordpress specialist to help us with this issue.

Anyone an idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without access to your site, we will not be able to help you. You will need to hire someone to actually investigate.

Comment: I'd follow their advice and find a WP developer that specializes in security / malware cleanup (although I just checked your website using two different browsers and none of them gave me that warning you're seeing.)

Comment: it seems one of your plugins installed is causing that. Uninstall you our plugins and check the site with out the plugins. then reinstall one plugin as you check the site. you will find the problem

Comment: i see, you have problems with theme52448, plugin - cherry-plugin. okay investigate you will find the problem